# Ubuntu fails to boot on a Windows 10 dual boot. It wasn't installed correctly

Tags: dual-boot, windows

So I tried to setup dual boot on my prebuilt Windows 10 machine and whenever I boot the system first it takes me to the windows boot screen where it asks you to choose between Windows and Ubuntu. Whenever I choose Windows it runs normally every time. But if I choose Ubuntu, Ubuntu won't even boot. Instead I see this black screen from the BIOS here is what it says:

> Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software chjange might
> be the cause. To fix this problem:
>
> 1. Insert  your Windows installation disc and restart your coputer.
> 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
> 3. Click "Repair your computer."
>
> if you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or
> computer manufacturer for assistance.
>
> File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
>
> Status: 0xc000007b
>
> Info: the application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a
> required file is missing or conatins errors.

So this error message is leading me strraight to the problem. That file it mentioned is bad so would I have to replace it with a new one?

Comment: Are you trying to run Ubuntu inside windows or boot one or the other separate from each?

Comment: The latter. As a matter of fact, I don't like using Windows and have backed up all of the data that I'd want to save. So I don't mind doing away entirely without Windows 10. To add complewxity to my issue, I actaully have two HDD's on my machine.

Comment: Then I would boot for a live CD or USB use gparted and remove all partitions and do a fresh clean install of Ubuntu. That is just what I would do in the situation you describe. Two hard drives is not complex just install to the first one.